# Why localstorage value overwrites in the different iframe's from the same origin?

Tags: html, iframe, local-storage

I have added two URLs of same domain name in the two  tag in a webpage.
For these URLs I am sending query parameter. The parameter is same but value is different.
This parameter value stored into the localstorage. 
The problem is the first iframes value of localstorage overwrites the second iframe's localstorage.
localstorage value is same for both iframes. But it should be different.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the Storage is shared for the whole origin, so that when you are in `https://yousite.net/page2` you can access the data that has been stored from `https://yousite.net/page2`.

Simply use more idiomatic keys to store your data, for instance `page_1_data` for `page1` and `page_2_data` for `page2`.